# Reliable way to call a function on browser close or before session timeout?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there a way to reliably invoke a function before the session expires or the window is closed? To avoid excessive mysql queries, my script will collect and change data variables in php `$_SESSION` variables and make mysql updates when there needs to be an interaction with the database. Since I'm storing this data in this manner, is there a reliable way to ensure that this data is committed to the database before the user closes the window, or before the session expires?

I have tagged php, javascript and jquery because I'm open to any method of doing so.

Addition: Sorry, we're presuming that the client has javascript enabled. I'm in a unique situation where I don't particularly care to serve a client that isn't.

Comment: How "excessive" are those queries? Because the only truely safe way of doing it, is to simply update the database right away. Otherwise, you'll have to rely on the client (browser) to not crash, have javascript running, and generally work perfectly. Alternatively, you'll need something running in the background in the server to do everything if you haven't had a request from the client in a while. Either way, it's tricky

Comment: @Flambino Well, the amount of queries aren't in the scope of the question, currently. Because the potential load on the server is variable. Each client could be having 3 queries every 1/10 of a second if I didn't handle the information via `$_SESSION`. We'll just presume that the amount of queries is non-affecting. The question remains the same.

Comment: What would happen if the user's internet connection suddenly dropped? I doubt you'll find anything completely reliable.

Comment: @jtbandes Okay, I'll settle for _relatively reliable_, even though I didn't say "bullet proof."

Comment: @jtbandes: depends how he defines a "session"

Comment: @Blake: I'd still say update the DB right away, and see if it can handle it. Premature optimization is a dangerous path to take. Besides, if you batch the queries and run them all at one time, you place all the load at one point in time rather than spreading it out. But if you insist on batching, I'm afraid I don't know of a sure-fire way of making it work.

Comment: @Flambino- I understand what you mean. I suppose I poorly clarified how it works. I am constantly receiving new data for the same variables. It seems silly to `UPDATE table SET var=1` then `UPDATE table SET var=2`, etc 600 times a second. The calculations are stored in a session variable until it has finished (also varying time per calculation). The queries aren't batched, but rather once the "set" (we'll call it) has finished then the variable, which has changed hundreds of times, is then stored.

Comment: @Blake: Ok, that makes more sense. However, structurally it would then make more sense to have the calculations all happen on the client or on the server, so the DB can update only once, when the value is final. I know it's not much of an answer, but finding some way of checking that the value's final is better than assuming it's final because it hasn't changed in a while. If that makes any sense :)

Comment: @Flambino- It does make sense. But unfortunately I'm trying to have the client interact with the script in real time. I could have it calculate the end result and print it out over the time it should taken to happen, but then the client wouldn't be able to interact with it. It is a difficult process to explain. Hence why if the browser closes, I want the current state to be saved so it may be continued upon return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon much searching / discussion. I will use a `setTimeout()` method to periodically commit the data to the database. The user can continue (with some possible data loss) upon return, similar to the google docs model.